# Firebase FCM (Javascript): Error when request permission (Error status = 500)

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to Firebase Cloud Messaging and I need to implement notifications in my webapp.
If the browser requests notification for the first time there is no error occurred and the token fetched successfuly. But if I delete the notification from the browser parametre (I use Chrome) and ask for permission again, it shows me an error in the console.

```
DELETE https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/teak-perigee-*****/registrations/dcVW8MdcapIy5CrSqGutkj:APA91bFoslZEsjgIk16CUfol*****************

FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occured while unsubscribing the user from FCM: FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occured while unsubscribing the user from FCM: Internal error encountered. (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed). (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed).
```

Actually the token is fetched even this error occurs. but in this situation I handle the new token in the `catch` block of the promise. This is my code when permission is fired:

```js
askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications = () => {

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    Notification.requestPermission().then(async (permission) => {

            if (permission == 'granted') {

                try {

                    const token = await messaging.getToken();

                    if (token) {

                        console.log(token);
                        return token;
                    } else {
                        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                    }
                } catch (error) {

                    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', error);


                    //BUT THE NEW TOKEN SUCCESSFULY FETCHED
                    const token = await messaging.getToken();

                    if (token) {

                        console.log(token);
                        return token;
                    } else {
                        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                    }
                }
            }

        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

I don't know if I miss something and I hope I can find a solution.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Can any one reply here?

Comment: does it happen to you only on localhost?

Comment: This answer and fix the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/75317314/16759195

Answer (score 7):

I faced a similar issue and believe this may be the explanation.

Issue was introduced in version 7.0.0 of the firebase-js-sdk. A workaround for now is to use version 6.6.2 or lower. I have filed a Github issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2364) for users effected to track.

So to enable use an older version just update the following in your index.html:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/6.6.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

and change the following to your service worker file (typically named: firebase-messaging-sw.js):

```
importScripts('/__/firebase/6.6.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/6.6.2/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Comment: Spent three hours trying to fix this in my project, thank you for this, fixed it straight away!

Answer (score 4):

it turns out that new versions of Firebase SDKs depend on a new internal infrastructure service, called FIS (the Firebase Installations Service) for targeting identifiers ("FIDs" or "Instance-IDs").
If you are using API key restrictions for the API keys you use in your application, you will have to extend those restrictions to allow usage with the new Firebase Installations Service at firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com.

To allow your API key in question to be used with the new Firebase Installations API:

- go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
- choose the relevant project (i.e. the project you use for your application)
- open the menu and go to APIs & Services -> Credentials
- click Edit API key for the API key in question
- scroll down to API restrictions
- from the dropdown, choose FCM Registration API
- click Save
- wait a couple of minutes for Google servers to update and retry...

Comment: This doesn't make sense - what's the relationship between the cloud console and firebase? This error comes up when testing the Firebase cloud messaging, with apps setup in the firebase console. There is no trie from the Firebase console to the Google Cloud Console - or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase library has a bug where it saves the token in an indexed database in your app. When you delete your credentials, it fails to delete the token and instead tries to fetch the old token when creating a new one, which leads to an error since the token no longer exists in Firebase. To resolve the issue, simply follow these steps.

-Open Google Chrome DevTools by pressing F12

-Click on the Application tab.

-Expand the Storage section in the left-side panel.

-Expand IndexedDB

-Expand firebase-messaging-database

-Right click on the key-value and delete it

-Refresh your app and the error is gone

Comment: This would fix your computer, but not a fix for other users of your app.

Comment: This is a quick fix, so that you can identify where the error is coming from. you must fix your source code for permanent fix to all your users